# Can't update my pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have created a [pod](https://github.com/LudaFuxPlaybuzz/playbuzz-ios-sdk) project. It is pushed and workes properly. 
Then I decided to make couple of updates. I've created a new tag, validated the code and pushed again.

```
git tag 0.1.2
git push origin 0.1.2
pod spec lint PlaybuzzSDK.podspec
pod trunk push PlaybuzzSDK.podspec
```

The process was successful. But when I try to do

```
pod update
```

In my [EmapleProject](https://github.com/LudaFuxPlaybuzz/playbuzz-ios-sdk/tree/master/Example), the pod roles back to what it was before. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pushing the `podspec` to the trunk again, version `0.1.2` doesn't seem to exist there:

[image]

You can also check your pod's status from `https://cocoapods.org/pods/[podname]`, in your case: https://cocoapods.org/pods/PlaybuzzSDK.

Comment: From the specs repo or from your git repo?

Answer (score 5):

Try this in terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Cocoapods
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

Cocoapods has it's own local cache of all the pods you're using locally. Sometimes when pushing a new pod spec up, the cache doesn't pick up the changes. Removing the cached repos and pod specs forces a fresh download the next time you do a `pod install`.

If you're not seeing it at that point, I'd make sure you've successfully pushed all tags (`git push --tags origin`) and that you didn't have any errors when you did `pod spec lint PlaybuzzSDK.podspec`.